# How can i make my id from 12-09CB1 to 12-09CB0001 in auto increment?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Hi I had used this following code

```
$last_id=mysql_query("select * from complaint_list order by complaint_id Desc Limit 1");
$complaint_last=mysql_fetch_array($last_id);

$complaintid=$complaint_last['complaint_id'];
$complaintid = str_pad($id, 4, '0');
$year = substr($get[0],2,2);
$complaint_number=$year."-".$get[1]."CB".$complaintid;

mysql_query("insert into complaint_list(complaint_number, sap_number, complaint_type, circle_id) values('" . $complaint_number . "','" . $_POST['sap_number'] . "', 'DU', " . $_POST['circle'].")");
```

It's showing all the time as 12-09CB0000.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I solved this issue,

Just replace this code

```
$last_id=mysql_query("select *,lpad(complaint_id,4,'0') as cid from complaint_list order by complaint_id Desc Limit 1");
    $complaint_last=mysql_fetch_array($last_id);
    $complaintid=$complaint_last['cid'];
    $complaintid = str_pad($complaintid, 4, '0');
    $year = substr($get[0],2,2);
    $complaint_number=$year."-".$get[1]."CB".$complaintid;
```

Comment: Do you still need to call `str_pad` now that you're padding in MySQL?